# Installing my Beta Android App on several devices for testing

Tags: android, apk

I have a Beta version of android app and I am looking to install on several devices of my organization for testing before publishing on market

- other than installing through ADB shell and android market. What would be possible way to do this.
- I don't want to use a third party solution like hockeykey.net . What would be the possible way to do it.

*if i had to make an installer how can do that

Any answer,link,suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you export the APK, you can load it on any device that allows side loading (you have to enable third party addons on the device).

You can even programmatically update the app if you have an server to download the updated APK from, circumventing the app market entirely.

Comment: how can i download the .apk from the server on to device. if so do i need any permissions. And how can i install the .apk (which comes from server)...thanks in advance

Comment: Step 1: Establish connection to server 
Step 2: download the new APK Step 3: save APK as something.apk Step 4: something like  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File
                     (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                     context.startActivity(intent);

Comment: And, as always, make sure you request all the permissions you need to do that. I believe its android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES and android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES (if you want to clean up the file afterwards.

Comment: so do i need to write a new application on the device  to do above steps programamtically? but i need to install this installing app again on all devices. can i bypass that. thanks again.

Comment: Well the first time it will be loaded using normal methods (like usb transfer, download of a website etc) Just put something in the program that allows them to check for updates (or do it on creation)

Comment: the installing app(in our case the installing code described above)..which installs our primary app....but even i have to install the installing app on several devices..i cant ask all users to install through usb but can ask to download from server...if they download from server...will the apk installer on device allow this installing app to install. may be I am wrong plz correct me ..thanks again

Comment: If you navigate to the APK via a file explorer, such as ASTRO file manager, it should install the APK.

Comment: so i guess i need to use some third party solution like astro file manager..unfortunately i cant do in the organization.. but if i enable the device on unknown sources..can the installer on device let me install.?  iam full of question now...thanks a lot .again :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but if you host the APK on a web service, and target it with the phone, it should download the apk and they should be able to install it via the download success notification. Sorry, this is starting to get into speculation. Hope all this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If your users have enabled unknown sources in preferences, you can send them the APK via email as an attachment, or have them download it from a webpage, and they should be prompted for installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute the .apk of your application and (with a file manager) the users will be able to install it.

Comment: is the file manager a installer software of android i need to make ? if so can u suggest me how can i do that.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best option, as some already mentioned, is to publish your .apk on a website.

You can have your testers to install any barcode scanner apps (a lot of free, available at Android Market). I like "Barcode Scanner" from ZXing team. And use any QR Code Generator (i.e. http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/) with the full URL to your .apk. Most of the devices won't have any issue.

Devices must have enabled to install from "Unknown Sources".

I recommend to have an .htaccess file to add .apk type (some browser have conflict if not set on server). And some other devices may not download it from stock Android Browser, so they may install any other free browser available on Android Market (such as Dolphin HD)

Comment: i cant use  unknown sources option,since it is of organization. Downloading the file is not a problem. But installing is.